# /byterange entry not found in pdf while reading using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, digital-signature, fortify

I'm developing a website for signing pdf files digitally using smart cards (using Fortify), in order to insert the signature into the pdf I have to use the /byterange entry
The code I'm working on now:

```
<script>
   async function continueHandler(event, pdf) {
     let pdfBuffer = buffer.Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(pdf));
     const byteRangeString = `/ByteRange `;
     let byteRangePos = pdfBuffer.indexOf(byteRangeString);

     if (byteRangePos === -1)
         throw new Error('asd');
   
     var provider = await event.detail.fortifyEvent.detail.socketProvider.getCrypto(event.detail.fortifyEvent.detail.providerId);
     
   
     provider.sign = provider.subtle.sign.bind(provider.subtle);
   
     pkijs.setEngine(
       "newEngine",
       provider,
       new pkijs.CryptoEngine({
         name: "",
         crypto: provider,
         subtle: provider.subtle,
       })
     );       
     var cert = await provider.certStorage.getItem(event.detail.fortifyEvent.detail.certificateId);
     var privateKey = await provider.keyStorage.getItem(event.detail.fortifyEvent.detail.privateKeyId);
     var certRawData = await provider.certStorage.exportCert('raw', cert);       
   
     var pkiCert = new pkijs.Certificate({
       schema: asn1js.fromBER(certRawData).result,
     });
   
     const hashBuffer = await provider.subtle.digest('SHA-256', pdf);
     const signedAttr = [];
   
     signedAttr.push(new pkijs.Attribute({
       type: "1.2.840.113549.1.9.3",// contentType (PKCS #9)
       values: [
         new asn1js.ObjectIdentifier({ value: "1.2.840.113549.1.7.1" })// data (PKCS #7)
       ]
     })); // contentType
   
     signedAttr.push(new pkijs.Attribute({
       type: "1.2.840.113549.1.9.5",// signingTime (PKCS #9)
       values: [
         new asn1js.UTCTime({ valueDate: new Date() })
       ]
     })); // signingTime
   
     signedAttr.push(new pkijs.Attribute({
       type: "1.2.840.113549.1.9.4",// messageDigest (PKCS #9)
       values: [
         new asn1js.OctetString({ valueHex: hashBuffer })
       ]
     })); // messageDigest
   
     
     var signedData = new pkijs.SignedData({
       version: 1,
       digestAlgorithms: [
         new pkijs.AlgorithmIdentifier({
           algorithmId: "1.3.14.3.2.26", 
           algorithmParams: new asn1js.Null()
         }),
       ],
       encapContentInfo: new pkijs.EncapsulatedContentInfo({
         eContentType: "1.2.840.113549.1.7.1", // "data" content type
       }),
       signerInfos: [
         new pkijs.SignerInfo({
           version: 1,
           sid: new pkijs.IssuerAndSerialNumber({
             issuer: pkiCert.issuer,
             serialNumber: pkiCert.serialNumber,
           }),
           digestAlgorithm: new pkijs.AlgorithmIdentifier({algorithmId: "1.3.14.3.2.26", algorithmParams: new asn1js.Null()}),
           signatureAlgorithm: new pkijs.AlgorithmIdentifier({algorithmId: "1.2.840.113549.1.1.5", algorithmParams: new asn1js.Null()}),
           signedAttrs: new pkijs.SignedAndUnsignedAttributes({
             type: "0",
             attributes: signedAttr,
           }),
         }),
       ],
   
       certificates: [pkiCert],
     });
   
     await signedData.sign(privateKey, 0, 'SHA-256', pdf);
   
     const cms = new pkijs.ContentInfo({
       contentType: "1.2.840.113549.1.7.2",
       content: signedData.toSchema(true),
     });
   
     const result = cms.toSchema().toBER(false);
   
     let stringSignature = Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(result), x => (`00${x.toString(16)}`).slice(-2)).join('');
     let lenSignature = result.byteLength;
   
     if ( (placeholderLength / 2) - lenSignature > 0 ) {
       stringSignature += Buffer
         .from(String.fromCharCode(0).repeat((placeholderLength / 2) - lenSignature))
         .toString('hex');
     };
   
     let output = Buffer.concat([
       pdf.slice(0, byteRange[1]),
       Buffer.from(`<${stringSignature}>`),
       pdf.slice(byteRange[1])
     ]);
   
     const a = document.createElement('a');
     const blob = new Blob([output], { type: 'application/pdf' });
     a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     a.download = 'pdf-signed.pdf';
     a.click(); 
   }
     
</script>
```

I'm getting error on this line:

```
if (byteRangePos === -1)
             throw new Error('asd');
```

which means that the pdf doesn't contain a /byterange
How to solve this issue and complete the signing process without corrupting the file ?